# kotlin wrong nullability inference without any generics

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

in spring mvc (5.1.3) i'm trying to do:

```
val url : String? = null
val matcher: ResultMatcher = MockMvcResultMatchers.forwardedUrl(url)
```

and i get compilation error for the second line.

from intellij (kotlinc-jvm 1.3.11):

```
Error:(230, 56) Kotlin: Null can not be a value of a non-null type String
```

or from gradle (kotlin 1.2.71):

```
 Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected
```

the java source code of spring method is:

```
/**
 * Asserts the request was forwarded to the given URL.
 * <p>This method accepts only exact matches.
 * @param expectedUrl the exact URL expected
 */
public static ResultMatcher forwardedUrl(String expectedUrl) {
    return result -> assertEquals("Forwarded URL", expectedUrl, result.getResponse().getForwardedUrl());
}
```

intellij displays javadoc:

```
org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers @NotNull 
@Contract(pure = true) 
public static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultMatcher forwardedUrl(@Nullable String expectedUrl)
```

so why the compiler still requires non-nullable type and how to bypass that requirement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no explicit nullability annotations on the parameter of `MockMvcResultMatchers.forwardedUrl`, so it will default to `@NonNullApi`, as indicated in the [`package-info.java`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/a89e716cc71a8741385a0224b5d7eb7ce009e11a/spring-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/package-info.java):

```
/**
 * Contains built-in {@code ResultMatcher} and {@code ResultHandler} implementations.
 * <p>Use {@link org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers}
 * and {@link org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers}
 * to access instances of those implementations.
 */
@NonNullApi
@NonNullFields
package org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result;

import org.springframework.lang.NonNullApi;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNullFields;
```

There's no way to describe nullability in Java, so by default passing both `String` and `String?` into a Java method that accepts a `String` would work. However, Kotlin compiler honors different flavors of nullability annotations (such as `javax.annotation.*`, Android's annotations, Spring's annotations) to allow Java code to provide nullability information to Kotlin callers.

How to bypass this? You can't. You're passing an argument of the wrong type 
 - `String` and `String?` are different types in Kotlin.

Answer (score -1):

`val url : String? = null`, then the variable `url` **is** `null` with nullable type `String?` since it is a immutable `val`. However I think we should ignore the mutability in this question.

To "nonnull" it, the [Elvis opeator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) can be used:

```
val matcher: ResultMatcher = MockMvcResultMatchers.forwardedUrl(url ?: "")
```

Or replace the "default" value into whatever you need.