# Gradle: kotlin tests can't see java files in test

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, junit5

java 8, gradle 5, kotlin 1.2.71, junit 5.3.2, intellij 2018.03 december 17, keeping kotlin and java files in the same src dir
the file structure is:

```
.
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper...
│       
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── kotlin
    │   │   └─ ...
    │   └── resources
    │       └── application.yml
    └── test
        └── kotlin
            └────── xxx
                    └── shop
                        └── order
                            ├── Junit5Kotlin.kt
                            ├── Junit5Test.java
                            ├── OrderITest.kt
                            ├── ProductITest.kt
                            └── Util.java
```

from intellij ('run all tests' clicked on 'test' dir) all works correctly. from `./gradlew test` test kotlin classes don't see java test util classes:

```
xxx.shop.order.Manual > should return client error on bad input FAILED
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: xxx/shop/order/Util
        at xxx.shop.order.Manual.before(ProductITest.kt:229)

        Caused by:
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xxx.shop.order.Util
            at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
            ... 1 more
```

and it's not a compile time error but runtime error as other tests finished successfully

potentially important parts of my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-spring'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-jpa'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'xxx.shop'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xjsr305=strict"]
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xjsr305=strict"]
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to put your java files in `java` dir or else they will not be compiled.

```
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── kotlin
    │   │   └─ ...
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └─ ...
    │   └── resources
    │       └── application.yml
   └── test
        └── kotlin
            └────── xxx
                    └── shop
                        └── order
                            ├── Junit5Kotlin.kt
                            ├── OrderITest.kt
                            ├── ProductITest.kt
                            └── Util.java
            java
            └────── xxx
                    └── shop
                        └── order
                            ├── Junit5Test.java
```

And add java plugin to gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

**EDIT:**
OK, if you want it all to be in kotlin dir, try to add this to you build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['src/main/kotlin']
sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs = ['src/test/kotlin']
```

This way it will run java compiler before kotlin one so you will have this `.class` files.

Comment: that's what i'm trying to avoid. i want to separate my code by functionality, not by technology

Comment: @piotrek mixing two technologies within one module is probably to root issue. when `Util.java` would be converted to `Util.kt`, it would in general be less complicated. when both technologies rely on it, consider putting it into a library module (which then can be tested independently).

Comment: @MartinZeitler yes, unless it's an existing project with thousands of java classes or part where kotlin can't cooperate with spring like https://stackoverflow.com/a/53908207/1100135

Comment: @piotrek moving `Java` code without proper `Kotlin` inter-operability into it's own module still would make it easier to handle... and even provide better overview, where the conversion stalls.